# How to handle RoutedEvent in DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've faced with the problem trying handle a RoutedEvent in DataTemplate. My code is below.

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="AdditionalTemplate">
            <Grid>
               ...
            </Grid>

            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="local:EditorView.HideView">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            ...                               
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>

        </DataTemplate> "HideView" event set in code behind
```

"HideView" event set in code behind such a way:

```
    public static readonly RoutedEvent HideViewEvent = EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("HideView", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(EditorView));
```

As result nothing happens after event calling.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use property in your view model?
Datatrigger disigned exactly for this purpose.
Changed your code in a way when your event change this property "MyProperty" and your EventTrigger  change to DataTrigger: <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}"...

Comment: Nice tip! I'll try it!

Comment: Please, write your help as an answer not a comment to let me mark it as solution.

Comment: Ok. It's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a property in your view model and replace your event trigger by DataTrigger:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyProperty}">
 <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            ...                               
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
</DataTrigger>
```

Changed your code in a way when your event raising changes this property "MyProperty". This will activate your data trigger and storyboard will run.

Comment: Thanks! But seems it's right to add <DataTrigger.EnterActions> before Storyboard.